# Postgres query optimizer in empty sets

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Imagine I have the following query (translated from JDBC):

```
select ta.indexedColumnA, tb.indexedColumnB
from tableA ta join tableB tb on ta.id=tb.foreignKeyA
where ta.id in (@listOfIds)
```

Now, the param @listOfIds can be a list with some ids (let's say [0,10] usually).

1. In case it's an empty list, is the query optimiser able to do some optimisation (such as return an empty result) ?
2. does the capability of optimising (short-circuit) depends on something we can control?

(I'm not sure of postgres version, will update as soon as I can be sure)

Comment: You can't really pass an empty list because `in ()` is invalid SQL

Comment: @pedrorijo would be an option to pass `null` instead of nothing as parameter? `where ta.id in (null)`

Comment: @JimJones: that's actually a good idea ;) Postgres will catch that and don't read anything from the table at all. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=630bfaf4f11655d3185d1de5e7ffc4a4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I also think that it might be the most elegant solution, I'm just not sure that it is what the OP needs :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by *@a_horse_with_no_name*: you cannot pass an empty set using `IN`. Take a look at the fiddle he provided in the comments.

What you can do is to pass a `NULL` value instead, which will return an empty result set:

Data sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (id int, val int);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,1),(NULL,2);
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE id IN (NULL);

 id | val 
----+-----
(0 Zeilen)
```